# How does WooCommerce get a user's country

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, woocommerce, country

Ok so I know that to get the current user's location in WooCommerce you use

```
$woocommerce->customer->get_country( );
```

Woocommerce then returns the user's country as a 2 character user code i.e (GB,US,MX) My question is, where is WooCommerce getting this value? even when I am logged out it seems to get the correct location. Is this some kind of Geo coding or it uses a cookie or database to return a user inputed value?

Comment: It seems the above country is taken from the user's address if he/she is logged in. If a user is not logged in, Woo commerce returns the ahops 'home' country set by the Admin in the Woocommerce settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using MaxMind API, class WC_Geolocation located inside includes folder. 
The MaxMind GeoLite Database will be periodically downloaded to your wp-content directory if you check to use geolocation, there is option in settings.

You can find talk when they added it to WooCommerce here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6969

Answer (score 1):

Never used WooCommerce before but in the past I have used [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) to get a users country and other information based on IP address. It's not always accurate though (country is likely to be accurate but city isn't)